# How to group many information une one select

Tags: mysql, join, select, pivot, sum

There are my database

```
articles
id | art_code | art_name
1  | 5678     | computer
2  | 0987     | display
3  | 8547     | keyboard

action
id | code        | action      | qte
1  | 5678        | IN          | 4
2  | 0987        | OUT         | 3
3  | 5678        | IN          | 6
4  | 5678        | OUT         | 2
```

I would like to SELECT all value of article with SUM() of IN / OUT group by article

ex:

```
RESULT:

    id | art_code | art_name  | IN  |  OUT 
    1  | 5678     | computer  | 10  |   2  
    2  | 0987     | display   | 3   |   NULL  
    3  | 8547     | keyboard  | NULL|   NULL
```

I try but, I've a result with :

RESULT:

```
    id | art_code | art_name  | IN  |  OUT 
    1  | 5678     | computer  | 10  |   NULL  
    1  | 5678     | computer  | NULL|   2  
    2  | 0987     | display   | 3   |   NULL
```

I can't have SUM(IN) and SUM(OUT) in 1 line by article.art_code.

An idea?

Comment: Maybe you could give us an SQL fiddle with CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements to give us something to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, art_code, art_name, SUM(`IN`) `IN`, SUM(`OUT`) `OUT`
FROM 
  ( SELECT a0.id, a0.art_code, a0.art_name, SUM(a1.qte) `IN`, NULL `OUT`
    FROM article a0
    LEFT JOIN action a1 ON a0.art_code = a1.code AND a1.action = 'IN'
    GROUP BY a0.id, a0.art_code, a0.art_name
  UNION ALL
    SELECT a0.id, a0.art_code, a0.art_name, NULL, SUM(a2.qte)
    FROM article a0
    LEFT JOIN action a2 ON a0.art_code = a2.code AND a2.action = 'OUT'
    GROUP BY a0.id, a0.art_code, a0.art_name
  ) sq
GROUP BY id, art_code, art_name
ORDER BY id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f69b03e0cc4756d28d1bb266fb758d7)

Comment: Akina, what is it the `sq` before GROUP BY?

Comment: @Stolker It is subquery alias (temporary subquery name). Can be almost any (restrictions - must comply with MySQL object naming rules and be unique within the query).

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is called *pivoting*. You essentially want the results grouped by `code` and `action` but re-arranged so that instead of one row per `code` and `action` you get one row per `code` only, all the distinct `action` values (well, just two in your case) forming separate columns.

In other words, instead of

```
action   code  value
-------  ----  ------
action1  IN    value1
action1  OUT   value2
action2  IN    value3
...      ...   ...
```

you are trying to get

```
action   IN      OUT
-------  ------  ------
action1  value1  value2
action2  value3  ...
...      ...     ...
```

Some SQL products support a dedicated `PIVOT` syntax. MySQL is not one of them, but you can use other ways.

One common way is *conditional aggregation*. You will group the rows by `code` only, because you want one row per `code` in the output. The aggregation by `action` will be achieved by introducing a conditional as the aggregate function's argument. This is how you code that in SQL:

```
SELECT
  art.id,
  art.art_code,
  art.art_name,
  SUM(CASE act.action WHEN 'IN'  THEN act.qte END) AS `IN`,
  SUM(CASE act.action WHEN 'OUT' THEN act.qte END) AS `OUT`
FROM
  article AS art
  LEFT JOIN action AS act ON art.art_code = act.code
GROUP BY
  art.id,
  art.art_code,
  art.art_name
ORDER BY
  art.id ASC
;
```

Each `SUM` expression aggregates `qte` just for one of the `action` values, either `'IN'` or `'OUT'`, using a `CASE` expression. As shown in the query, you need two `SUM` expressions, one per each value of `action`. If you had more, you would need to add more `SUM`s accordingly.

However, as there only two values here, it may make sense to try alternative methods. One such alternative is in [Akina's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/232214/6965). Here is another option:

```
SELECT
  art.id,
  art.art_code,
  art.art_name,
  act_in.`IN`,
  act_out.`OUT`
FROM
  article AS art

  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT code, SUM(qte) AS `IN`  FROM action WHERE action = 'IN'  GROUP BY code
  ) AS act_in
  ON art.art_code = act_in.code

  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT code, SUM(qte) AS `OUT` FROM action WHERE action = 'OUT' GROUP BY code
  ) AS act_out
  ON art.art_code = act_out.code

ORDER BY
  art.id ASC
;
```

As you can see, getting each of the two columns (`IN` and `OUT`) requires one outer join to a derived table containing the aggregated results for the corresponding `action` value. It is easy to see how this approach would not be a good idea if you needed to produce ten such columns. Not only would the query itself become cumbersome much more quickly than the conditional aggregation method, but the performance would deteriorate very soon too. However, for just two columns this option might be worth a shot.

Both suggestions presented in this answer can be found and played with [at dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=44729126253cbacfc6cd3eb0d9a3f365) (the setup was borrowed from Akina's fiddle):

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.art_code, a.art_name,(select sum(qte) from test_action where art_code = a.art_code and action = 'IN') as [IN], (select sum(qte) from test_action where art_code = a.art_code and action = 'OUT') as [OUT] from test_articles a left join test_action ac on ac.art_code = a.art_code
```

Try this query, I think you might have the incorrect expected result. 
Coded in Microsoft SQL Server